# Jest 'projects' configuration does not read .babelrc and webpack.config.json in subfolder

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs, babel-jest

I need some help configuring jest with babel in a mono repo,

my project layout looks like:

```
src/some/path/packages
                      /jest.config.js
                      /a/src/jest.config.js
                      /a/src/.babelrc
                      /a/src/webpack.config.js
                      /b/src/jest.config.js
                      /b/src/webpack.config.js
```

and my root jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    projects: ["./a/src/jest.config.js", "/b/src/jest.config.js"]
};
```

a/src/jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    resolver: "jest-webpack-resolver"
};
```

as you can see i'm using the webpack resolver because i have aliases in my webpack.config.js files

if i call jest in the ./a/src it works perfectly
but if i call it in packages it

- Cannot resolve the modules and
- ES6 imports don't work and I get SyntaxError's (.babelrc is apparently not found)

I want to prevent having to install babel / jest /
   webpack in applications and i cannot figure out how to make jest use
   the correct .babelrc file

I've also attempted to change the jest.config.js in packages/ to this:

```
module.exports = {
    projects: [{
        rootDir: "<rootDir>/a/src",
        resolver: "jest-webpack-resolver"
    },
    {
        rootDir: "<rootDir>/b/src",
        resolver: "jest-webpack-resolver"
    }]
};
```

but also to no avail.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: no unfortunately not yet

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the exact same problem. I took me a while to figure this one put, but I managed to solve it with my own version of `babel-jest` called `babel-jest-nested`:

https://github.com/lehni/babel-jest-nested

With this, I can specify my projects at the root level in `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  projects: ['<rootDir>/packages/*']
}
```

I also have a `jest.base.config.js` on the root level that each project / package will load:

```
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest-nested'
  },
  testMatch: [
    '**/src/**/?(*.)+(test).js'
  ]
}
```

Then, within project / package, I simply do this, again in a `jest.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  ...require('../../jest.base.config.js')
}
```

and suddenly, it all works. Magic.

Comment: I've filed an issue with jest to include this functionality in `babel-jest`: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6617

Comment: But what if you need to **override** some config? You would need to do a deep clone and merge the base config and the child config?

Comment: Update: It's better to use this approach now: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6053#issuecomment-383632515